# Hamburger glyph (&#9776;) renders gray on Android devices

Tags: android, html, css

Suppose this simple website with gray background and white text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background: gray; color: white; font-size:50px;" >
  I should actually <br>
  be white: &#9776;
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, the text renders white as expected, but the hamburger menu created with `&#9776;` seems to render in a dark, beveled style:

[image: Gray hamburger menu on Galaxy S7]

I suspect this is some sort of proprietary icon style that is substituted. Is there a way around this or a viable alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Using `&#8801;` instead of `&#9776;` seems to solve this problem. Although this glyph is a bit smaller.

[image: White hamburger menu on Galaxy S7]